# Is my understanding of divisibility correct? (Divisibility with negative numbers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

From what I am getting from my textbook:
$a\rvert b$ if there exists at least one $c∈Z^+$ such that $ac=b$

So let's say I need to show that 2 divides 10. Then from the definition of divisibility, there exists some $c∈Z^+$ such that $2c=10$. We can then say $c=5$ and since $5∈Z^+$ then ultimately we can say that $2|10$.

So now let's say I need to show 1 divides $-5$. Then from the definition of divisibility, there exists some $c∈Z^+$ such that $(1)(c)=(-5)$. Then we can say that $c=(-5)/(1)=(-5)$ but $(-5)∉Z^+$. So then I can say that 1 does not divide $(-5)$?

Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Your definition of divisibility is not the one most of us use. $a|b$ if there exists $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ac=b$. No restriction of positive $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When negative integers are involved at all, the relevant concept of divisibility is that $a\mid b$ iff there is a $c\in \mathbb Z$ such that $b=ac$. There is no requirement that $c$ must be positive.

With this definition, set of the numbers that $a$ divides is exactly the smallest [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) of $\mathbb Z$ that contains $a$.

On the other hand, the set of *positive* multiples of $a$ doesn't have any particularly nice algebraic properties.